# removing items representing a time from a select box if their time is past

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, drop-down-menu, momentjs

I have a select box that looks like this where I have times from 5:00 AM to 8:45 PM in increments of 15 minutes. In JS or JQuery I want to take the current local time in JS/JQuery and then remove all times before the current time. ex. if it's 4:01 PM, remove all options before 4:15 PM

```html
<select name="selectBox" id="selectBox">
  <option value="1">5:00 AM</option>
  <option value="2">5:15 AM</option>
  <option value="3">5:30 AM</option>
  <option value="4">5:45 AM</option>
  ...
  ...
  ...
  <option value="63">8:45 PM</option>
</select>
```

How can I calculate the values I need to remove given a local time from moment.js? I can get the hours (0-23) and the minutes(0-59)

Comment: Two points: You could set up a function which takes a list of values. Loop through the values and run your jQuery remove.  Secondly, you asked two very unrelated things in the same question.  These should be separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to remove options after printing it. You can ignore printing invalid options. See my code below.

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById("sel");

var selectList = document.createElement("select");
selectList.id = "mySelect";
myDiv.appendChild(selectList);

var date = new Date("", "", "", 5, 0, 0) // our start time
var cur = new Date() // gets current date
var curhr = cur.getHours() // get current hours 
var curmin = cur.getMinutes() // get current minutes 
var curTime = new Date("", "", "", curhr, curmin, 0) // creates new time 
var hours = Math.abs(curTime - date) / 36e5; // finds the difference
var printFrom = Math.abs(hours / .25) // converts it into a value b/w 0-63

var min = 45;
var hr = 4;
var end = " AM"; // for printing AM and PM
for (var i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
  min += 15;
  if (min % 60 == 0) {
    min = 00;
    hr++;
  }
  // setAttribute("disabled", "true")

  // prints valid option
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  if (i <= parseInt(printFrom)) {
    option.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
  }
  option.value = i;
  if (hr == 12) {
    end = " PM";
  }

  if (min % 60 == 0) {
    option.text = hr.toString() + ":00" + end;
  } else {
    option.text = hr.toString() + ":" + min.toString() + end;
  }
  selectList.appendChild(option);
}
```

```html
<div id="sel"></div>
```

Note: I have updated my answer to disable invalid options. If it's not needed, you can remove the else part `i > parseInt(printFrom)`.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand your solution. If i > parseInt(printFrom) then I can disable, right?

Comment: @user1186050 No, the else part of the condition disables invalid options.

Comment: so then it's the opposite?

Comment: @user1186050 I have updated my answer to bring more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You could define two functions: one that converts a sequence number (1 - 64) to a time string, and another that returns the sequence number that corresponds to the current time.

Then use these to first populate the complete list box upon page load (maybe you don't need this?), and then one that keeps it updated by deleting entries that have passed:

```js
function quarterToTime(i) {
    i--; // Make relative to zero
    return ('0' + (((Math.floor(i / 4) + 4) % 12) + 1)).substr(-2) + ':' 
           + ('0' + ((i * 15) % 60)).substr(-2) 
           + (i >= 28 ? ' PM' : ' AM');
}

function nextQuarter() {
    var dt = new Date();
    return (dt.getHours()-5)*4 + Math.ceil(dt.getMinutes() / 15) + 1;
}

// Fill complete list upon page load
for (var i = 1; i <= 64; i++) {
    $("#selectBox").append($("<option>", { value: i }).text(quarterToTime(i)));
}

// Keep list updated
setInterval(function () {
    var quarter = nextQuarter();
    $("#selectBox > option").filter(function () {
        return +this.value < quarter;
    }).remove();
}, 1000); // Every second. Could be every minute.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selectBox" id="selectBox"></select> (Adapts after 1 second)
```

Comment: this seems a little too complex. I think I'm going to try and find a solution where I just calculate which numbers 1-63 that I need to disable and then from the hours and minutes find out which numbers they are. Then loop through and add a disabled to the option tag

Comment: Thats exactly what the function in setInterval does. But instead of disabling I removed them.